# Conditional query logging in Jooq

Tags: java, sql, jooq

We have a custom execute listener for logging DB queries, How do we filter out queries to be logged only for certain table names?
At the moment every query executed is logged.

This is our current listener.

```
@Override
public void executeStart(ExecuteContext ctx) {
    // Create a new DSLContext for logging rendering purposes
    // This DSLContext doesn't need a connection, only the SQLDialect...
    Settings setting = new Settings();
    setting.withRenderFormatted(true);
    setting.setExecuteLogging(true);
    StringBuilder message = new StringBuilder();
    DSLContext create = DSL.using(ctx.configuration().dialect(),
            // ... and the flag for pretty-printing
            new Settings().withRenderFormatted(true));
    // If we're executing a query
    if (ctx.query() != null && ENABLE_LOGGING) {
        LOGGER.debug(message.append(DynamicApplicationConfig.getStringProperty("API_ENV","dev"))
                .append(" - ")
                .append(create.renderInlined(ctx.query())).toString());
    }
    // If we're executing a routine
    else if (ctx.routine() != null && ENABLE_LOGGING) {
        LOGGER.debug(message.append(DynamicApplicationConfig.getStringProperty("API_ENV","dev"))
                .append(" - ")
                .append(create.renderInlined(ctx.routine())).toString());
    }
    // If we're executing anything else (e.g. plain SQL)
    else if (!StringUtils.isBlank(ctx.sql()) && ENABLE_LOGGING) {
        LOGGER.debug(message.append(DynamicApplicationConfig.getStringProperty("API_ENV","dev"))
                .append(" - ")
                .append(ctx.sql()).toString());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Robust solution: `RenderContext`

jOOQ queries generate a SQL string through the [`RenderContext`](https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org/jooq/RenderContext.html) API, which is an API that is passed to every jOOQ `QueryPart` in order to produce SQL string contents and bind variables. You could implement your own and pass that through a query in order to collect all the tables that are contained in the query.

Note that the `RenderContext` API might receive new methods in later minor releases, so this implementation might break between releases.

#### Robust solution: `VisitListener`

jOOQ knows a [`VisitListener`](https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org/jooq/VisitListener.html) SPI, which allows you to hook into the rendering lifecycle. The idea of this SPI is to be able to modify the generated SQL content ([e.g. to implement more sophisticated multi-tenancy or row level security features](https://blog.jooq.org/2015/06/17/implementing-client-side-row-level-security-with-jooq/)).

In your case, you wouldn't manipulate the jOOQ expression tree, but simply collect all the tables that are being rendered, and store them in some place accessible to the logger.

This solution might have a small impact on rendering performance.

#### Quick and dirty solution: Regular expressions

For completeness' sake (as I'm sure you had thought of this yourself), I'm listing a trivial solution that would log the message only if a certain regular expression matches the SQL string, e.g.:

```java
if (ctx.query() != null && ENABLE_LOGGING 
                        && ctx.sql().matches("(?i:.*?\\bmy_table_name\\b.*)") {
    LOGGER.debug(message.append(
             DynamicApplicationConfig.getStringProperty("API_ENV","dev"))
          .append(" - ")
          .append(create.renderInlined(ctx.query())).toString());
}
```

Of course, your actual regular expression might be more sophisticated

#### Quick and dirty solution: Using reflection to access internals

You could, of course, try to access the `ctx.query()`'s internals, where the table references are stored. I'm not documenting this here, as it is subject to change, being internal.

But for completeness' sake it's worth mentioning, as this might be a good enough solution in your case.

Comment: Is there a way to append a comment /* DEBUG */ to the query in the VisitListener if any of the tables we want to log are detected. Then in the DefaultExecuteListener we just check for the above string and log the entire query.

Comment: @user160108: You can use [`ctx.data()`](https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org/jooq/Scope.html#data--) to "signal" the presence of a certain table. This can then be picked up by the closing call to `visitEnd()`, when the query is finished. Something similar is done in [the linked article about row level security](https://blog.jooq.org/2015/06/17/implementing-client-side-row-level-security-with-jooq/). If you want to communicate with your `ExecuteListener`, you'll have to set that up yourself.